# Cartoon in the 90s-00s with a scene of a short haired woman dancing

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm looking for a specific scene from a cartoon and after an hour of research I can't find it.

I'm pretty sure it was from a "Batman" cartoon series, possibly "Batman Beyond", and it was featured in the opening credits. The scene, which was a handful of seconds long, shows a short-haired woman dancing in a club; the light goes on and off, simulating a stroboscopic effect, and every time the light is back "on", the woman is in another dancing pose. In the last such scene, the woman's face becomes a creepy skull.

Comment: I think I found a gif of the scene through creative searches, not sure which show/ep it's from (confirm it's the right one, please?): https://i.imgur.com/OZbI9q4.gif?noredirect

Comment: Yes, correct! Thanks a lot! Which show could it be?

Comment: Looks like it's a music video actually of a Pearl Jam song, although animated by someone who worked on Batman, hence style similarities.  Full answer incoming.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This seems to be the scene you're thinking of:

[image]

It's not actually from a series at all, but rather from the [music video of Pearl Jam's song "Do the Evolution"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDaOgu2CQtI).

According to the [Wikipedia entry on the song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_the_Evolution):

> The animated music video for "Do the Evolution" was co-directed by Kevin Altieri, known for his direction on Batman: The Animated Series, and Todd McFarlane, better known for his work with the popular comic book Spawn and Korn's 1999 "Freak on a Leash" video.[10] The video was produced by Joe Pearson, the president of Epoch Ink animation, and Terry Fitzgerald at TME. It was written and developed by Pearson and Altieri with input from McFarlane and Vedder.[10] The total production time on the music video was 16 weeks.[10] The animation pre-production was produced by Epoch Ink Animation at their studio in Santa Monica, California. Under Altieri and Pearson’s supervision the Epoch team boarded and designed the short in less than six weeks.[10] Once McFarlane, Vedder, and Sony gave their final approvals, the short was taken to Korea by Altieri and Pearson for animation at Sun Min Image Pictures and Jireh Animation. Over a four-week period, a team of more than one hundred artists worked to deliver the finished animation.

The co-director's experience on the Batman animated series probably explain the similarities that made you think it was from a Batman series.

It probably does still count as sci-fi/fantasy though, because as the wikipedia summary of the video puts it:

> Throughout the video, a black haired woman (similar in appearance to the character Death from the DC comic book series, The Sandman) dances and laughs, representing "Death" as it follows mankind through all of its history.

and

> The video concludes in what seems to be future scenarios of the self-destruction of the human race, including the carpet bombing of a city of clones by futuristic aircraft, computers hijacking the human mind, and finally a nuclear explosion which leaves not only a city in ruins, but the planet damaged beyond recognition.

Comment: Terrific answer, thank you from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: I read _The Sandman_ too many times - I saw the girl in the gif and immediately thought "Death?!", and then read the description.

Comment: The art style does feel a lot like batman TAS. Without the context, this looks almost like something out of TAS or Batman Beyond

Comment: yeah, that was the first idea when I read the question.